# How to find a proper basis defined on (111) plane such that only one component of piezoelectric field is nonzero?

Tags: solid-state-physics, tensor-calculus, material-science, crystals, piezoelectric

I am considering a material which has cubic crystal structure (in particular, zincblende). The space group is $T_d^2 F \bar{4}3m$. In particular, I am concerned with finding the piezoelectric field in the [111] direction after being subject to some strain $S$. In my case, I work with the 'strain-voltage' form of the piezoelectric equations, and I am in one dimension with conditions that ultimately yield the equation for the piezoelectric field as:
$$E_m = g_{ij}^k s_{k\ell}^{ij}S_{\ell m} \Longleftrightarrow [E]_{(3\times 1)}=[\mathfrak{g}]_{(3\times 6)}[s]_{(6\times 6)}[S]_{(6\times 1)}$$
where $\mathbf{E}$ is the piezoelectric field tensor, $\mathfrak{g}$ is the voltage piezoelectric tensor, $\mathbf{s}$ is the compliance tensor, and $\mathbf{S}$ is the strain tensor. Due to symmetry of the cubic crystal structure, it can be readily verified that the matrix representation of the 3x6 piezoelectric tensor has only three nonzero elements, all of which are equal, $g_1^4$. Multiplying the matrix representation of all of the tensors ultimately gives an answer for the electric field like
$$\begin{bmatrix}E_1 \\ E_2 \\ E_3 \end{bmatrix}=g_1^4 c_{12}^{12}\begin{bmatrix} S_4 \\ S_5 \\ S_6 \end{bmatrix} $$
It is assumed that this is all evaluated in the standard Cartesian basis $\{\hat{\mathbf{x}},\hat{\mathbf{y}},\hat{\mathbf{z}} \}$. The question now becomes, how to select a basis such that the electric field is of the form that only one of its three components is nontrivial, and that this component corresponds to the $[111]$ direction in the standard basis.

My first idea has been to identify a desired basis defined on the edge of the hexagonal (111) plane, in which the normal basis vector $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_3$ corresponds to the vector $\langle 1,1,1\rangle$ in Cartesian coordinates. The other two vectors in this basis $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1$, $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_2$, must be orthogonal to $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_3$ but not mutually orthogonal due to them being defined on the edge of a hexagonal plane. I am not even sure if this will obtain the desired result, but I am nonetheless stuck here and finding this basis.

Any advice will be appreciated.